# How do I set up a free Bitcoin eStore

Tags: merchants

I want to sell digital products (eBooks) using Bitcoin, and I want products to be instantly available after purchase. What could I do?

Comment: Are you looking for a prepackaged solution you can use, or are you looking to build something yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Coinbase has shopping cart plugins that can integrate with many existing e-commerce web apps without you having to write any code. See here: https://coinbase.com/docs/merchant_tools/shopping_cart_plugins.

In case you were wondering, an "e-commerce web app" is a pre-build shopping website that is analogous to Word Press for publishing. There are a few open source (free) options for this. Just google "open source e-commerce web app".

Answer (score 0):

Bitpay offer a payment gateway service like this, and seem to be the processor of choice (at least at many of the retailers I have used),  That said they do charge for the service, and if you have some programming skill it would not be too hard to do this.

**Process**

- User Finishes shopping, Goes to Cart and selects pay by Bitcoin.
- System Presents user with a bitcoin address and specifies amount.  (Would recommend placing a time limit on this to protect against market movements.)
- system then watches address on blockchain for transaction to appear (recommend waiting at least 3 confirms)

**Security Considerations**

due to the very exploitable nature of web services I would suggest that you keep your bitcoind off the web server and do one of the following.

- Set up a proxy application on the second server that only implements 2 RPC commands getnewaddress and list transactions.
- have no direct connection to your wallet at all.  each day generate say 1000 new address's and then load them into the sales server.  You can then use the blockchain.info api to watch for the transaction and have zero interaction with your wallet where the coins would go.